# Highlight the values with color inside multi columns table

Tags: tables, fonts, table-of-contents, color, tabularx

I am trying to highlight the values inside the multi-column table, but I am not getting the exact result.

So my table looks like this:

[image]

code

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[review]{emnlp2021}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}
\definecolor{mycolor}{gray}{0.8}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}

Example of color code \colorbox{mycolor}{ \footnotesize  [SEP] }

\begin{table*}[t!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.85\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l|c@{ }c@{ }c@{ }|c@{ }c@{ }c@{ }|ccc@{ }}
    \toprule
    {} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bf Metric A} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\bf Metric B} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bf Metric C}\\
    \midrule
    \bf Model & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Precision} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Recall} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\bf F1-score} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Precision} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Recall} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\bf F1-score} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Precision} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Recall} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf F1-score} \\
    \midrule
   
  modela & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
  modelb & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
  modelc & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
  modeld & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 92.13 & 92.38 & 92.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
  modelf & 95.21 & 95.54 & 95.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 97.06 & 98.31 & 99.08 \\
    
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{Performance of all baseline models
    }
    \label{tab:accbinary_token}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

I am using [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/emnlp-2021-template/hqchdxrsnwjs)

I defined a custom color code like this:

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{gray}{0.8}
```

Now, if I am trying to colour the rows of the table,

```
\colorbox{mycolor}{95.21 & 95.54 & 95.28} & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 97.06 & 98.31 & 99.08 \\
```

its showing like this:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

How I can colour the different rows of multi-column like the above table?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227584/color-in-table-with-multicolumn-and-multirow-how-to-achieve

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178976/how-to-color-a-cell-of-a-table-using-multirow-and-center-th

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended to rescale tables with `\resizebox` because that leads to inconsistencies in the width of the rules.

That's why I have composed the table in a `{sidewaystable}` of `\rotating`.

For the gray shapes under some rows, I have used `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

That environment is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells. It's possible to use those nodes with Tikz to draw whatever we want under the tabular.

```
pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{emnlp2021}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}


\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}l|c@{ }c@{ }c@{ }|c@{ }c@{ }c@{ }|ccc@{ }}
    \CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
       \begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style = {fill=gray!20,rounded corners}]
          \node [fit = (7-2) (7-4)] {} ;
          \node [fit = (6-5) (6-7)] {} ;
          \node [fit = (7-8) (7-10)] {} ;
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \Body
    \toprule
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\bfseries}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Metric A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Metric B} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Metric C}\\
    \midrule
    Model & Precision & Recall & F1-score & Precision & Recall & F1-score & Precision & Recall & F1-score \\
    \midrule
      modela & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
      modelb & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
      modelc & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
      modeld & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 92.13 & 92.38 & 92.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
      modelf & 95.21 & 95.54 & 95.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 97.06 & 98.31 & 99.08 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{Performance of all baseline models
    }
    \label{tab:accbinary_token}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

---

For a better design, may people will recommend you to use only horizontal rules, for example (in the spirit of `\booktabs`):

```
pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{emnlp2021}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}


\begin{document}



\begin{sidewaystable}[t!]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}lccccccccc@{}}
    \CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
       \begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style = {fill=gray!20,rounded corners}]
          \node [fit = (7-2) (7-4)] {} ;
          \node [fit = (6-5) (6-7)] {} ;
          \node [fit = (7-8) (7-10)] {} ;
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \Body
    \toprule
    \Block{2-1}{Model}  & \Block{1-3}{Metric A} &&& \Block{1-3}{Metric B} &&& \Block{1-3}{Metric C}\\
    \cmidrule(rl){2-4} \cmidrule(rl){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
    & Precision & Recall & F1-score & Precision & Recall & F1-score & Precision & Recall & F1-score \\
    \midrule
      modela & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
      modelb & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
      modelc & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
      modeld & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 92.13 & 92.38 & 92.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
      modelf & 95.21 & 95.54 & 95.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 97.06 & 98.31 & 99.08 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{Performance of all baseline models
    }
    \label{tab:accbinary_token}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. The second table appears Vertical, and I need it horizontal.

Comment: You should use `{table}` instead of `{sidewaystable}` and try to use `\small`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't package `emnlp2021`, so I can only suspect that it defines (among others) also two column page layout. This layout is mimic with `twocolumn` options in `article` document class.

Bay using `tabularray` package and `\footnotesize` column headers fonts, can be fit your table across two columns and simple color selected cells:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage[review]{emnlp2021} % I haven't this package
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    %\small
\begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
             colspec={l @{\qquad} *{10}{X[c]} },
             cell{7}{2-4} = {bg=gray!20},  % cells background color
             cell{6}{5-7} = {bg=gray!20},
             cell{7}{8-10}= {bg=gray!20},
             row{1,2} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
            }
    \toprule
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Metric A
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  Metric B
                    &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Metric C
                                &   &           \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
    \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
    \cmidrule[l]{2-10}
Model   & Precision & Recall    & F1-score
        & Precision & Recall    & F1-score
        & Precision & Recall    & F1-score      \\
    \midrule
model a  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
model b  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
model c  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
model c  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
model d  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Performance of all baseline models}
    \label{tab:accbinary_token}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you for some reason prefer that all cell  are "jailed" by horizontal and vertical lines like this:

[image]

than you only need to change above MWE as follows:

- add `\hlines` and `vlines` to `tblr` preamble
- delete all rules in table body
- slightly change `colspec` (see MWE below)

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage[review]{emnlp2021} % I haven't this package
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    %\small
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,             % <--- added 
             colsep = 4pt,
             colspec={l *{10}{X[c]} },   % <--- chNGED
             cell{7}{2-4} = {bg=gray!20},
             cell{6}{5-7} = {bg=gray!20},
             cell{7}{8-10} = {bg=gray!20},
             row{1,2} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries}
            }
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Metric A
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  Metric B
                    &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Metric C
                                &   &           \\
Model   & Precision & Recall    & F1-score
        & Precision & Recall    & F1-score
        & Precision & Recall    & F1-score      \\
model a  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
model b  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
model c  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
model c  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
model d  & 92.21 & 92.54 & 92.28 & 90.13 & 90.38 & 90.19 & 89.06 & 89.31 & 88.08 \\
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Performance of all baseline models}
    \label{tab:accbinary_token}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time; how to resize this table as above in my code?

Comment: @AadityaUra, why you like to resize your table? Is it to wide? Try to reduce font size, and `colsep`. Where I can get `emnlp2021` package?

Comment: Hi, Need to fit other content in the paper that's why I need to make the size small.

Comment: @AadityaUra, ah, you try to put an elephant into lady suitcase :-).  Don't doing this. Since table can float, there is no reason to scale a table.  Since your situation is unknown to me (us), is hard to sensible advise. As I say, try to use smaller size of  font in table and reduce vertical space with declaring `rowsep=1pt` (default is 2pt) in table preamble.